# Get all text in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, selenium, text, beautifulsoup, attributes

I am unable to extract the text. There is no error on my machine but I am 
getting the tags to on my `CSV` too.

I have tried `.text` and `.text()` on the end of form:

> soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'result'})....I get errors.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
form = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'result'})

for post in form:
    print(post)

csv_writer.writerow([post])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: `post.text`, `post.get_text()` (event stripped: `post.get_text(strip=True)`

Comment: always if you get error then show it in question.

Comment: `form` is a list with many elements. You can't use `.text`, `.text()` or `.get_text()` on list. You have to use it on every element separatelly - `post.text`

Comment: @furas I am not sure if I am doing this properly I did print(post.text) and print(post.text()) and got this error:                                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", line 47, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow([post])
NameError: name 'post' is not defined

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you have to use `writerow([post.text])` inside loop `for post ...`

Comment: you're amazing! it's working well now